# How to resolve view pushing problem of Android keyboard when clicking on EditText?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, user-interface, android-edittext

In my Android app, when a user clicks on EditText the keyboard appears and just pushes all the screen views upwards dislocating my UI components.

How can I solve this issue, I want the keyboard to overlay over my UI components and then the user can type what he/she wants.

Comment: Can you explain with out code ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the activity in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: Welcome. You can mark the answer as accepted if it solves the issue for you so others can find it helpful.